# Autocomplete functionality on textbox keyup event

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, autocomplete

The first part of the code is used for creating multiple texboxes in `gridview`.

In the second part I want to use autocomplete functionality on textboxes `keyup` event.

The second part is not working.

```
$(function () {
            $('#cpContent_grdOrderDetail tr').attr('data-count', '0');
            $('.bull').click(function () {
                var NewRow = $(this).closest('tr');
                var SrNo = $(this).closest('tr').find('.GridTextBox').val();
                var no = parseInt(NewRow.attr('data-count'));
                var newx = no + 1;
                NewRow.attr('data-count', newx);
                var ProductId = $(this).closest('tr').find('#hfProductId').val();
                $(this).closest('tr').find('#hfAttachmentCount').val(no);
                alert(ProductId);
                var content = '<tr><td></td>';
                content = content + '<td><input type="text" ID="txtAttachmentCode' + SrNo + '_' + no + '" class="AttachmentAutoFill" /><input type="hidden" class="AttachPId" ID="hfProductId' + SrNo + '_' + no + '" Value=' + ProductId + ' /></td>';
                content = content + '<td><input type="text" ID="txtAttachName' + SrNo + '_' + no + '" /></td>';
                content = content + '<td colspan=2></td>';
                content = content + '<td><input type="text" ID="txtAttachmentQty' + SrNo + '_' + no + '"/></td>';
                content = content + '<td><input type="text" ID="txtAttachCost' + SrNo + '_' + no + '"/></td>';
                content = content + '<td colspan=3></td>';
                content = content + '<td><input type="text" ID="txtAttachmentTotalCost' + SrNo + '_' + no + '"/></td>';
                content = content + '</tr>';
                $(content).insertAfter(NewRow);
                return false;
            });

            $(document).on('keyup', '.AttachmentAutoFill', function () {
                var ProductId = $(this).next('.AttachPId').val();
                var FilterText = $(this).val();
                $(this).autocomplete({
                    source: function (request, response) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService/GetItemsForAutoCompleteBox.asmx/GetAttachmentInfo") %>',
                            data: "{ 'ProductId': '" + $(this).next('.AttachPId').val() + "',FilterText'" + $(this).val() + "'}",
                            dataType: "json",
                            type: "POST",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            success: function (data) {
                                response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                                    return {
                                        label: item.split('-')[0],
                                        val: item.split('-')[1]
                                    }
                                }))
                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            },
                            failure: function (response) {
                                alert(response.responseText);
                            }
                        });
                    },
                    select: function (e, i) {

                    },
                    minLength: 1
                });
            });
        });
```

Comment: Is there any error ??

Comment: there is not any error problem is its not going inside autocomplete function i.e $(this).autocomplete({

Comment: Add your html markup to your question or make a fiddle

Comment: Its a .net page and code is to big @R.K.Saini

Comment: Hmm ok, have you tried to console.log in keyup event to make sure its firing or not.

Comment: Yes keyup event is firing I am also getting ProductID and Filtertext value but it is not going inside autocomplete function @R.K.Saini

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem with your ajax call when you send data to your request you call `$(this).next('.AttachPId')` but inside $.ajax $(this) is not refer to input box so you need to save it outside the scope and then you can use it inside ajax.

```
 $(document).on('keyup', '.AttachmentAutoFill', function () {
        var ProductId = $(this).next('.AttachPId').val();
        var FilterText = $(this).val();
        var postData = {'ProductId':ProductId,'FilterText':FilterText};
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/WebService/GetItemsForAutoCompleteBox.asmx/GetAttachmentInfo") %>',
                    data: postData ,
                    // other config stuff
                    success: function (data) {
                       // your success callback goes here
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {

            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks but still its not working it is not going inside autocomplete function @R.K.Saini

Comment: Are you still using $(this).next('.AttachPId').val() in ajax  ?

Comment: If i dont use next how can i get the ProductId value and .AttachPId is Hidden field class name as u can see it in my first code.... and sorry for asking too many questions as my Javascript and Jquery is weak

Comment: For testing i commented the line containing next keyword still its not going inside autocompete function

Comment: You get me wrong I am not saying that you cannot use .next() to get a product value. I am just saying that not use $(this) to refer the textbox inside ajax because inside $.ajax $(this) not refer to textbox

Comment: Can you check is it firing ajax call or not ?

Comment: Used the code given by you but still the same problem

Comment: Got the code from this link http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Populate-jQuery-AutoComplete-TextBox-from-Database-using-Web-Service-in-ASPNet.aspx..... should I export the script for the same

Comment: Check your network tab inside developer tool to see if it fire ajax request or not. If you are using firebug it will be inside console tab

Comment: It doesn't seem right to "setup" auto complete on each keyup; isn't that what `$(this).autocomplete({...` is doing in your case? Do you have a reason to do this?

Comment: @G.Stoynev Yes, you are right using autocomplete on keyup is overkill. OP should initialize autocomplete on some other event